# How to sign transaction from frontend with metamask and then send that signed data to rest api for submitting the transaction?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3j

I have a front end connected with metamask wallet and a rest API layer.

My requirement is to sign the transaction from metamask and then to send the signed transaction to rest api to submit the transacion.

Comment: Do you have code sample of what you have tried ?

Comment: yes, I have tried to sign by web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction() method ,But it is expecting the private key which we can't get from the metamask.

Comment: have you looked at this? https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask

Comment: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4

Answer (score 0):

I think if metamask sign a transaction they broadcast it to the network. You can retrieve data from the transaction with a callback if you want.

If you want to sign a transaction offline, don't use Metamask but a local file with web3js and your private key hardcoded.